# My sprite is working in jsfiddle (included), but shows up as a blank page on my asp.net site. Any ideas?

Tags: asp.net, css, sprite

Thanks to @jimbertucci and @Biff MaGriff, I was able to finally make a sprite image and actually get the css right.  My website is asp.net / vb.

It **works great in jfiddle**!  [This is my sprite fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jasonpaulweber/QWEKA/) which is what I'd like it to be like.

SE wants me to include some code, so here's basically what I'm doing.  For CSS:

```
.clients{
width:231px;
height:136px;
background-image: url(http://www.ussvision.com/images/sprite_clients.jpg);
}
.gm{
background-position: 0px 0px;
}
```

For my html, I'm trying to call my sprite image this way:

```
<a href="http://www.gm.com" target="_blank">
    <div class="clients gm"></div>
</a>
```

But for some reason, when I upload it to the server, the page shows up and is the proper size.  The links are there when you hover around. The sprite seems to be functional, just except you can't see it; it's a blank page with **no image(s) showing**!

When I view the page source, I can see my divs and classes.  I don't see anything pointing to my sprite image, which is sprite-clients.jpg; I don't know if I should see that in the page source or not ... I don't know what I could be doing wrong.  Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You shouldn't need to have an absolute reference to your sprite image, and I know IIS can get funny about what it perceives as an external request. What happens if you eliminate the domain (use '/images/sprite_clients.jpg')?

Comment: lol ... whaaaaa?  I just took your suggestion, @Tieson T, and BAM, it works perfectly now!  That's bizarre!  I really do appreciate your suggestion.  Submit it as an answer and I'll mark it as resolved.  Thanks a bunch for taking the time to read and respond to my question -- saved me a huge headache!

Comment: You can add your own answer and mark it as accepted. I've been trying to find something in the MSDN that explains why IIS behaves this way; hence, the "what happens when..." suggestion/comment rather than an answer. :p

Comment: Okay ... I'll just mark it as accepted in two days, and then when you figure it out, I'll change my accepted answer.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not really answering my own question, but @Tieson T suggested that I try just using **../images/sprite-clients.jpg instead of the full http path**.  For whatever odd reason, that did the trick!  When I use http://domain.com/images/sprite-clients.jpg, it shows up blank.  But when I took Tieson's suggestion, it showed up in all browsers immediately (tested in IE8, FF, Chrome, and Safari).

If you're curious to know why IIS7 does this, or whatever is the cause of this, Tieson may check back in with a more complete answer when he can find out the reason.